# Lists.GetListItems list.asmx

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, web-services, xml

```
mlNode listNode = listSvc.GetList("{...}");
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
query.InnerXml = "";
XmlElement queryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");
queryOptions.InnerXml = "";
XmlElement viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
viewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name='MiddleName' />";
XmlNode ndListItems = listSvc.GetListItems("{...}", string.Empty, query, viewFields, string.Empty, null, null);
xmlDoc.LoadXml(ndListItems.OuterXml);
XmlNodeReader xmlReader = new XmlNodeReader(xmlDoc);
DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
DataColumn MiddleName = dtable.Columns.Add("MiddleName", typeof(String));
foreach (DataRow row in dtable.Rows)
{
  foreach (XmlNode listItem in ndListItems)
  {
     row["MiddleName"] = listItem.OuterXml;
  }
}
dataSet.Tables.Add(dtable);
```

When i debug it, I see what `dtable` is empty. But `ndlistItem` contain some data like it:

```
<listitems xmlns:s="uuid:..." xmlns:dt="uuid:..." xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<rs:data ItemCount="1">
   <z:row ows_MiddleName="..." ows_MetaInfo="..." ows__ModerationStatus="0" ows__Level="1" ows_ID="..." ows_UniqueId="...;#{...}" ows_owshiddenversion="2" ows_FSObjType="...;#0" ows_Created="..." ows_PermMask="..." ows_Modified="..." ows_PersonalDataProtection="1" ows_FileRef="...;#Lists/UserProfile/..._.000" />
</rs:data>
</listitems>
```

How take `ows_MiddleName` in `row["MiddleName"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < n.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes.Count;i++)

{

if(n.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[i].Attributes!=null)

Console.WriteLine("Event " + n.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[i].Attributes["ows_Title"].InnerText + " begins on " + n.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[i].Attributes["ows_EventDate"].InnerText);

}
```

[source](http://geekswithblogs.net/mcassell/archive/2007/08/22/Accessing-Sharepoint-Data-through-Web-Services.aspx)